# Embedding custom functions and calling them without defining

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, embedding, built-in

Is it possible to embed and call custom functions like embedded functions instead of writing them in every project?
So can we make a custom function an builtin function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: May be I am not getting the problem here, but writing a module *once* and importing it wherever it is needed in any project is not convenient enough already? BTW, what is an embedded function in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (kind of) using the `import` statement
For example:
project 1:

```py
#filename is project_1

def function_1():
    print("This has been executed from project 1")
```

And then in the main file that you want to use it in:

```py
import project_1

def function_2():
    print("This has been executed from project 2")

project_1.function_1()
function_2()
```

OUTPUT:
This has been executed from project 1
This has been executed from project 2

The only constrain to this is that you have to make sure that the 2 (or more) files are in the same directory otherwise you won't be able to import them.